# How to filter a dataframe keeping the highest value of a certain column

Tags: julia

Given the dataframe below, I want to filter records that shares the same `q2, id_q, check_id` and keep only the ones with the highest `value`.

input dataframe:

| q1 | q2 | id_q | check_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sdfsdf | dfsdfsdf | 10 | 10 | 90 |
| hdfhhd | dfsdfsdf | 10 | 10 | 80 |

There are 2 `q2` with same `id_q, check_id` but with different `values`:  90,80.

I want to return for the same `q2, id_q, check_id` the line with the highest value.  For example above the output is:

So I want to drop duplicates regarding to: `check_id` and `id_q` and keep the one with the highest value of `value`column

Desired Output:

| q1 | q2 | id_q | check_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sdfsdf | dfsdfsdf | 10 | 10 | 90 |

Comment: Looks like you want to `groupby` by your wanted columns `q2, id_q, check_id` and aggregate column `value` by the `max` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select rows of a DataFrame containing minimum of grouping variable in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024962/select-rows-of-a-dataframe-containing-minimum-of-grouping-variable-in-julia)

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024962/select-rows-of-a-dataframe-containing-minimum-of-grouping-variable-in-julia (with max instead of min)

Answer (score 0):

For this case this code seems to be shorter that the ones referenced in other answers:

Suppose you have

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=["a","a","b","b","b","b"], b=[1,1,2,2,3,3],c=11:16,notimportant=rand(6))
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b      c      notimportant
     │ String  Int64  Int64  Float64
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ a           1     11      0.93785
   2 │ a           1     12      0.877777
   3 │ b           2     13      0.845306
   4 │ b           2     14      0.477606
   5 │ b           3     15      0.722569
   6 │ b           3     16      0.122807
```

Than you can just do:

```
julia> combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]), :c => maximum => :c)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b      c
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ a           1     12
   2 │ b           2     14
   3 │ b           3     16
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle the columns that are neither part of the `groupby` key nor the maximised column (eg. `q1` in the dataframe in the question). For those to be part of the output, you'll have to do some kind of `argmax`-indexing, and at that point the answer in the linked question is probably the shorter, simpler one.

Comment: @SundarR It seems that this just ignores those columns which is the expected behavior as I assume. I edited the answer to show that. Or am I misunderstood something? - please let me know!

Comment: OP's "Desired Output" does contain `q1`, that's why I assume ignoring it isn't the expected behaviour for them. 

But it's useful to have this as one of the solutions, for anyone else who does want this behaviour.

Comment: Ah OK - you are right in that case `argmax` is in duplicate questions

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by [Przemyslaw Szufel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9957710/przemyslaw-szufel).

In case anyone is interested in also keeping the rest of the columns based on the argmax you could use something like this:

```
using DataFrames: DataFrame
df = DataFrame(a=["a","a","b","b","b","b"], b=[1,1,2,2,3,3],c=11:16,notimportant=rand(6))

combine(groupby(df, [:a,:b])) do sdf; sdf[argmax(sdf.c), :]; end
```

Gives you:

```
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b      c      notimportant
     │ String  Int64  Int64  Float64
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ a           1     12      0.641334
   2 │ b           2     14      0.737422
   3 │ b           3     16      0.27423
```

You can even put it in form of a function like:

```
function get_latest(df,id_symbols,sort_symbol)
    return combine(groupby(df, id_symbols)) do sdf; sdf[argmax(sdf[!,sort_symbol]), :]; end    
end
```

For anyone looking to keep more than 1 top result, i.e. the 5 greatest, I recommend looking [at this answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-select-top-5-results-per-group-in-dataframe/47149/3).